# How can I figure out what is calling my AWS services so often?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, spring-boot-actuator

I'm running five services on AWS. Each service has two instances (running as tasks in ECS).

I'm using Spring Boot Actuator, and processing some of the default metrics that that pushes.

I'm getting a lot of HTTP requests when the system is idle, and I can't figure out what they are.

My metrics are reporting 260 (ish) requests every 5 minute interval. It's been like that since I created my metrics, so I assume this was the case beforehand too.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Cloudwatch http requests grouped by status type]

I thought it might be health checks, but that doesn't add up.
5 services x 2 instances of each is 10, with 2 checks per minute is 20, which works out at 100 requests every 5 minutes.
What is going on here?

My Metrics insight query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM("http.server.requests.count") FROM test GROUP BY status
```

Where `test` is the namespace.

I have also created my own metrics, that are contained in a common package that is used with all my services. For one metric I implement a `HandlerInterceptor` that wraps any methods that use `@RequestMapping` (or other variants like `@GetMapping`) annotations and times the request. I added a `http.status` dimension to that metric and it returns the expected results.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to log the requests, what endpoint they are hitting, e.g. what data they are sending, from where the request is coming, etc.

Comment: Only logging the requests can answer your question decisively. The only thing someone here can do is provide guesses. I will point out that health checks will be 2 requests per minute, **per region the load balancer is deployed to**, per target group target. So they could easily add up to 100 requests per 5 minutes.

Comment: @MarkB am I correct in thinking that multiple load balancers will also result in a doubling of the amount of health checks? I think so right?

Comment: @mal yes that is correct as well.